# show a video file

Tags: c#, video

I want to show a video file in my windows application.
Please help me with details.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can install a Windows Media Player component and go:

player1.URL = @"filename.avi";
player1.Ctlcontrols.play();

Visit: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/53d1071b-26d9-406a-877c-3b33eedf8a4c/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Media Player COM control to show video in your Windows app.  You'll first need to add the Windows Media Player control to your toolbox in Visual Studio, then drag the control to your Windows form in Design view.

In your code, you can then set the URL property of the control to whatever video you want to play, like so:

```
// you may also use the full local path to the video, as opposed to a URL
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95772";
```

Source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) component in WPF. Easy and straight forward to use.